# Software for seafloor survey planning, for geological use cases

Tags: survey, planning

I am looking for recommendations from geologist that have done seafloor surveys using marine seismic methods that have found particular types of software useful for the planning, optimising and costing of their survey activities.

The use case can be for gas/oil prospecting, offshore wind farm planning or similar activities. I have seen a couple of software applications but this appears to be a very niche area (and sensitive because of large oil and mining companies).

Maybe there are mostly in-house developed applications but I am wondering if there are good commercial and open source tools out there, or similar types of applications that can be adapted to do this type of work.

Comment: What OS should it run on? What is your price margin? Any specific features to name?

Comment: @Izzy I guess there is probably a trade-off when it comes to performance if we are comparing web-based applications to desktop programs, and the pricing is probably affected by that as well. I don't really have a price range in mind and I think the use cases are specific enough to define the features required (but feel free to point out any that you can might be relevant if you have used some before).

Comment: I've not really used any such, though I've visited the seafloor more than once (being a scuba diver). Guess the area is already quite narrow, as you pointed out – so I just wanted to make sure there's no disappointment because of those points. // I vaguely remember there's an Android app called Cave Survey which might come close to it, as it's for underwater caves… ah, [here it is](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astoev.cave.survey). A quick search shows there seem to be Mac and Windows versions around as well.